# Generate a username with random numbers behind

Tags: php, function, random, numbers

So far I got only this which generate random numbers instead.

```
function randomUsername() {
    $number = "0123456789";
    $username = array();
    $numberLength = strlen($number) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $numberLength);
        $username[] = $number[$n];
    }
    return implode($username);
}
```

The output will be like "user34534" for example with a the word "user" in front and the random number behind. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
return implode($username);
```

to

```
return "user" . implode($username);
```

Comment: This answers your initial question.

Comment: Strange, but it cause my website to render HTML error 500, internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate random numbers instead of your function:

```
echo 'user' . uniqid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do random numbers is

```
$numberone = rand(1, 9);
$numbertwo = rand(1, 9);
$numberthree = rand(1, 9);
$numberfour = rand(1, 9);
$numberfive = rand(1, 9);
```

So...

```
"user" . $numberone . $numbertwo . $numberthree . $numberfour . $numberfive;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `"$user.rand(0,999999)"`. Assumption is that the $user is being supplied by a person registering. If not and the value of $user will always be the same e.g user, then try `"user".rand(0,999999)` 
Note that `rand(0,999999)` in this case will generate a random number between 0 and 999999 every time it is used.